# Shrink and Rotate a triangle

Tags: objective-c, ios, animation

How would I animate a triangle where the animation consists of shrinking the triangle and, at the same time, rotating it around its center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this

```
#define degreesToRadians(x) (M_PI * x / 180.0)

  [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^ {
    triangle.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadians(480));
    triangle.frame = CGRectMake(triangle.frame.origin.x + triangle.frame.size.width / 2, triangle.frame.origin.y + triangle.frame.size.height / 2, 0.0, 0.0);
  }];
```